# How to serialize this specific json format in C#

Tags: c#, json

Upon populating values in the object, When i serialise the OverallMainUserActivity object, i couldnt get the exact format required. Is it possible to have this outcome from serialisation of object in C#?

Expected Format:

```
{
"Registration": [
    {
      "1": "10",
      "2": "2",
      "3": "20",
      "4": "20",
      "5": "20",
      "6": "20",
      "7": "20",
      "8": "20",
      "9": "20",
      "10": "20"
    }],
"Withdrawal": [
    {
      "1": "10",
      "2": "2",
      "3": "20",
      "4": "20",
      "5": "20",
      "6": "20",
      "7": "20",
      "8": "20",
      "9": "20",
      "10": "20"
    }]
}
```

I have tried

```
 public class OverallUserMainActivity
  {
     #region Not_suitable
     public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Registration = new KeyValuePair<string, string>();
     public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Withdrawal = new KeyValuePair<string, string>();
     #endregion

     #region Not_suitable
     public Dictionary<string, string> Registration = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     public Dictionary<string, string> Withdrawal = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     #endregion

     #region Not_suitable
     public List<RegistrationCls> Registration = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
     public List<WithdrawalCls> Withdrawal = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
     #endregion
  }
```

Is there a special way to use array to get the expected format?

Comment: If you are using visual studio - there is a "PASTE SPECIAL" option in the edit menu. Copy the JSON into memory and this will create the class for you when you click "Paste JSON".

Comment: why not  put the inner scores in an inner array instead of an object?

Comment: am in short of understanding @Bindrid suggestion and first comment taught me a good feature in VS which i didnt notice for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` should work

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8FFZG2)

I only did the bare minimum to show it working, in your case you would probably have some nested loops or LINQ queries to translate your data into the `List` items and `Dictionary` items

Comment: am sorry, second attempt was dictionary only, editing the question

Comment: Thanks, but there is a square bracket in the expected format which is missing when having in dictionary